# How to align this rollover image with the center of the page?

Tags: html, css

Why won't this rollover image align to the center of the page?
I've tried all ways of aligning it that I could think of, but none works.

```
<img src="IMG1" align="middle" 
     onmouseover="this.src='IMG2'"
     onmouseout="this.src='IMG1'" width="1008" height="175"/>
```

I can't get it to center horizontally in the middle of the page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to vertically align an image inside a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-vertically-align-an-image-inside-a-div)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to wrap your image in a `<div>` set to display flex (I wouldn't set `<body>` to flex).

Flex box will let you place the image in the middle of your `<div>` very quickly! If you want your container it to take the screen full height simply set your `<div>` wrapper to 100vh.

Also notice that you shouldn't put your sizes after the forward slash.

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="img1" onmouseover="this.src='img2'" onmouseout="this.src='img1'"/>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:center;
  height: 100vh;
}

img {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/dusjG.png"
       onmouseover="this.src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RSNI.jpg'"
       onmouseout="this.src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/dusjG.png'"/>
</div>
```

[See also my codepen.](https://codepen.io/fabioioio/pen/NwXyMQ)

I hope this helps!

Comment: That didn't work :( is there a better way, it's a rollover image so there's three